# Change default reboot time for Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, automatic-update

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to change the default time which Windows 10 - Windows Update schedules my PC to reboot?  I most often just send my PC to sleep (or it does it automatically on inactivity) instead of shutting it down.

Of course Windows 10 sometimes schedules a reboot to occur at approximately 3:30am.  This causes my PC to wake in the early hours of the morning (along with me - since its in the same room as I am).

At the moment I am checking Windows Update to see if a reboot has been scheduled each night before I go to sleep but this is crazy.  What I'd like to do is change the default time that Windows sets the reboot to occur.  Any ideas?

Comment: More than likely it is windows update software that schedules a hard coded reboot time in task manager, I found nothing in the registry. This would explain why changing the setting is only good for the current reboot session. Or I could be wrong....

Comment: If you can move the automatic updates to happen earlier in the night (e.g. two hours after your usual bedtime), your PC may be be less likely to wake you up.  Also, even if it does wake you, you may find it easier to fall back asleep.  The night will still be young, so you'll still be quite tired.  But I don't know whether or not it's possible to change the default update time.

Comment: Some possible workarounds:  You could change your computer's clock by a few hours (or even by twelve hours), but this might cause your computer to have problems validating website security certificates.  Alternatively, you could use "hybrid sleep" or "hibernation" then use a power bar or surge suppressor or switched "lamp outlet" to cut off power to your PC.  Make sure to press the Off button on each of your devices — especially on any inkjet printers — before you cut their power off.

Comment: Some possible workarounds: You could change your computer's clock by a few hours (or even by twelve hours), but this might cause your computer to have problems validating website security certificates. Alternatively, you could use "hybrid sleep" or "hibernation" then use a power bar or surge suppressor or switched "lamp outlet" to cut off power to your PC. You should make sure to press the Off button on certain devices — especially on inkjet printers which have a usual shutdown routine — before you cut their power off.

Answer (score 1):

#### What I'd like to do is change the default time that Windows sets the reboot to occur

As you correctly noted in your question the default reboot time is 3.30 AM.

The following instructions show you how to change the reboot time.

> Windows 10 now allows you to specify a time for the computer to reboot
>   after updates are installed to finish the installation.
>
> To schedule a restart for updates:
>
> 1. Click the "Start" menu icon and select "Settings" on the Start menu.
>
>    [image: 01_clicking_settings]
> 2. On the "Settings" screen, click "“Update & Security".
>
>    [image: 02_clicking_update_and_security]
> 3. The "Windows Update" screen displays by default.
>
>    - If you have updates available, Windows will start downloading them and preparing to install.
>    - Click the "Advanced options" link.
>    - The update process will continue even though you are leaving the main "Windows Update" screen.
>
>    [image: 03_clicking_advanced_options]
> 4. On the "Advanced Options" screen, select "Notify to schedule restart" from the drop-down list at the top of the screen.
>
>    [image: 04_selecting_notify_to_schedule_restart]
> 5. Click the left arrow button in the upper-left corner of the screen to return to the "Windows Update" screen.
>
>    [image: 05_clicking_back_arrow]
> 6. You are notified that a restart has been scheduled and options are provided for you to schedule a time for the restart to happen.
>
>    - The first option provides a suggested time to restart the machine to finish installing the update.
>    - To specify a different time and date, select the "Select a restart time" option and specify a "Time" and "Day".
>    - For the "Time", click the box, hover your mouse over each part of the time (hour, minutes, and AM/PM) and scroll through the options
>        until you reach what you want.
>
> Note:
>
> - When you choose "Notify to schedule restart" you will be **prompted via a system notification to select a
>     specific restart time every time an update has been downloaded and
>     your PC needs a reboot**.
>
>   - This tweak does not pause update restarts, it only notifies you that a restart is required soon. Windows will schedule its own reboot first, and you must override it manually by scheduling your own.
>
>   [image: 06_scheduling_a_restart]
>
>   7. There should also be a "Restart Now" link you can click to restart the machine now to finish the updates immediately.

Source [How to Schedule Restarts for Updates in Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/221903/how-to-schedule-restarts-for-updates-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Yes I can change the specific time for any reboot.  I want to change the default reboot time so that I don't have to repeat that process over and over.

Comment: You cannot change the default reboot time as far as I am aware. When you choose "Notify to schedule restart" as described in the answer, you will be **prompted via a system notification to select a specific restart time every time an update has been downloaded and your PC needs a reboot**

Comment: This tweak does not pause update restarts, it only notifies you that a restart is required soon. Windows will schedule its own reboot first, and you must override it manually by scheduling your own.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill.  I appreciate the effort to explain how to reschedule the reboots, it may well be useful to others.  I am still hoping that there is a way to set the default reboot time and you're right, there is no setting for it.  I expect it will require a registry hack to achieve the goal.